# Running selenium grid hub with https protocol

Tags: selenium-grid

I am running selenium grid in a secured private network. I want to receive request to hub in https protocol instead of http.

Simply,

```
Grid console: https://X.XX.XX.X:4444/grid/console
Grid : https://X.XX.XX.X:4444/wd/hub
```

I got to know about Ngnix server for receiving side and serve the request to hub and also reverse proxy for running hub in behind, but no idea how exactly to be done.

If anyone did in above or in other way. Please let me know.